# Laravel Vuejs axios login change component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I built a basic login function (backend written in laravel), I do an axios call successfully but I fail to show the home component, the url changes but the ui stays the same `this.$router.push('/home');`

My Login.vue login logic:

```
    login() {
        console.log(this.getLoginData());
        axios.post("/login", {
            email: this.email, 
            password: this.password
        })
            .then(response => {         
                console.log("success");
                this.$router.push('/home');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error");
            })
```

The url changes to /home but the ui does not change.

my router:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Login from '@auth/Login';
import Home from '@/js/components/Home';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
    ]
});

export default router;
```

This is my app.js

```
import App from '@/js/views/App';
import Auth from '@views/Auth';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: Routes,
    store: PdfStore,
    render: h => h(Auth)
});

export default app;
```

App.vue holds the ui which shall be used after the login proccess.
App.vue holds a `<router-view></router-view>` and the navigation logic in App.vue works fine updating url and changing component.

It just does not work after the login process.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })`

Comment: same effect, url changes ui not

Comment: I suggested that because your route is named "home" but the actual route is "/". Does it take you to "home" if you push this.$router.push('/') instead of this.$router.push('/home')?